# Does this series converge or diverge? Stuck on finding the limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Say I have this sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n^3} + \frac{1}{3^n})$$

So this is close to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3}$ which converges because it's a p series where $p = 3$ which is > 1 so converges. But this series is actually bigger than $\frac{1}{n^3}$ so I can't use a standard comparions test. But I will try a Limit Comparison test:

[image]

So:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{n^3} + \frac{1}{3^n}) * \frac{n^3}{1}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^3}{n^3} + \frac{n^3}{3^n}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 1 + \frac{n^3}{3^n}$$

but what is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^3}{3^n}$

Can I use L'Hospital rule here? What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^3}{2^n}$ similarly?

Is this right:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^3}{3^n}$$

$$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3n}{3^n*ln(3)}$$

$$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3}{3^n*ln(3)^2} = 0$$

Is that right?

So the result of the limit comparison test then = $1 + \frac{n^3}{3^n} = 1$

so the original series converge too.

Comment: YTou just have to say that the sum of two convergent series is convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making a lot of calculations for nothing... The sum of convergent series is convergent, you already noted that $\sum \frac{1}{n^3}$ is convergent, and the rest is a geometric series with $|r|=\frac 13 < 1$, which is also convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Compare to $\sum\frac{2}{n^3}$. Or split into two separate sums $\sum\frac1{n^3}$ and $\sum\frac1{3^n}$.